# Query Statement: Using DISTINCT but also using MAX condition

Tags: conditional-statements, max, distinct

I have a table in my db which is minimally represented below. Note that there are entries under PRV that are duplicates.

| PRV | MV | AU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G-111 | 500 | LR |
| G-112 | 400 | LC |
| G-112 | 401 | LA |
| G-200 | 650 | LI |
| G-115 | 350 | LR |
| G-115 | 0 | LC |
| G-115 | 0 | LA |
| G-116 | 0 | LR |

I used the following query statement to get a count of the number of distinct PRV grouped according to AU.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    AU
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            PRV,
            AU
        FROM
            tablename
        WHERE
            MV > O
    ) AS K
GROUP BY
    AU
```

RESULT:

| `COUNT(*)` | AU |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | LR |
| 1 | LC |
| 0 | LA |
| 1 | LI |

What I can't figure out is how to make sure that the grouping is not just based on `MV>0`
but also on `MV` being the max among duplicate `PRVs`.

For the last 3 rows (where `PRV = 'G-115'`), my query statement works alright because the row with
AU = LR has MV=350 while the others have zero. Thus, G-115 is counted as just one unit and grouped under LR.

But, in the case of the 2nd and 3rd row (where PRV = 'G-112'), it is indeed counted as just 1 (because of the DISTINCT keyword), but I want it to be grouped as LA (not LC) because LA's MV = 401 (which is greater than MV=400 in the LC row).

So, the desired result would be:

| `COUNT(*)` | AU |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | LR |
| 0 | LC |
| 1 | LA |
| 1 | LI |

I read about `MAX` keyword but I can't figure out how to use it in my case.

In my actual table, the `distinct` keyword doesn't seem to work for rows 2 and 3. They are actually counted twice because `MV > 0` for both entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  m.AU,
  COUNT(x.MV) 
FROM mytable m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    PRV,
    MAX(MV) as MV
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY PRV) x ON x.PRV = m.PRV and x.MV = m.MV
WHERE m.MV > 0
GROUP BY m.AU;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/fhnoQoVS)

The left join, to the subquery which calculates the MAX value for MV does make sure you do not count the LC value, because it does not have the MAX value.

output:

| AU | COUNT(x.MV) |
| --- | --- |
| LR | 2 |
| LC | 0 |
| LA | 1 |
| LI | 1 |

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Luuk. I am on my mobile phone right now, so I can’t test it on my computer immediately. I’ll get back to you as soon as I get access to my PC.

Comment: Hi @Luuk, it worked and gave results that I expected.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder if I could still ask some follow up questions here, but I'll try anyway. I've applied the above answer at work and it helped a lot, but I'm having trouble with PRVs with equal values. Like, if instead of G-112 having MVs of 400 and 401, it has MVs of 400 & 400, the result of the query is no longer correct because it counts both rows.  Are there possible changes I could make to accommodate duplicate values of MV?

Comment: There are too many guesses about your data I need to do, I think asking as new question with complete description of this additional rule, and example data would be better.

Comment: yup, I did not foresee that and I only bumped into the 'equal max value' scenario recently. Thanks for the suggestion to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I could not think of a easy solution based on your original query above.
This method uses PARTITION BY (assuming your database supports it).  Here we partition by PRV and sort by PRV and MV descending, so the results have ROW=1 for the highest PRV+MV combination.
Then we sum the results accordingly:

```
  ;WITH 
    data
    AS
    (
    SELECT
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRV ORDER BY PRV, MV DESC) AS ROW
    FROM
        prv
    WHERE MV > 0
    )
    SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN ROW = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      AU
    FROM
      data
    GROUP BY AU
```

Comment: Our small office (with only around 150 users) uses only MySQL on PhpMyAdmin. I have yet to check if PARTITION is supported. I’ll give an update as soon as I test this out on my office PC. Thanks @Stewart .

Comment: Hi @Stewart, applying your query statement resulted in the following error; 

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'data"

I am presently also researching on the use of 'PARTITION BY' as they look really useful in my tables, not to mention that it looks elegant as well. So far, I have yet to wrap my mind around it. Thanks.