# MAX Values with possible Duplicate maximum values in same GROUP

Tags: join, max, distinct

I have received answers from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162177/query-statement-using-distinct-but-also-using-max-condition) about getting a count of the number of distinct PRVs grouped according to AU, considering only those with MV>0 that I posted in here and it worked wonders when I applied it to my actual work database.

However, I just bumped into a problem I did not forsee. The query statement does not work when it comes to duplicate maximum values of MV in the same group.

Again, here's the sample table:

| PRV | MV | AU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G-111 | 500 | LR |
| G-112 | 400 | LC |
| G-112 | 401 | LA |
| G-200 | 650 | LI |
| G-115 | 350 | LR |
| G-115 | 0 | LC |
| G-115 | 0 | LA |
| G-116 | 0 | LR |

and here's the query statement:

```
SELECT
  m.AU,
  COUNT(x.MV) 
FROM mytable m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    PRV,
    MAX(MV) as MV
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY PRV) x ON x.PRV = m.PRV and x.MV = m.MV
WHERE m.MV > 0
GROUP BY m.AU;
```

which gives this result:

| AU | COUNT(x.MV) |
| --- | --- |
| LR | 2 |
| LC | 0 |
| LA | 1 |
| LI | 1 |

But in the following case: (where G-112 now has both MV of 400 for both LC & LA):

| PRV | MV | AU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G-111 | 500 | LR |
| G-112 | 400 | LC |
| G-112 | 400 | LA |
| G-200 | 650 | LI |
| G-115 | 350 | LR |
| G-115 | 0 | LC |
| G-115 | 0 | LA |
| G-116 | 0 | LR |

The result would become:

| AU | COUNT(x.MV) |
| --- | --- |
| LR | 2 |
| LC | 1 |
| LA | 1 |
| LI | 1 |

So, G-112 is now erroneously counted twice.

The desired result would be either:

| AU | COUNT(x.MV) |
| --- | --- |
| LR | 2 |
| LC | 0 |
| LA | 1 |
| LI | 1 |

or

| AU | COUNT(x.MV) |
| --- | --- |
| LR | 2 |
| LC | 1 |
| LA | 0 |
| LI | 1 |

So, how do I factor in the possibility of duplicate values such as described above, so that only one of them is counted?

With my limited knowledge, I tried on dbfiddle messing with the statement; trying INNER JOIN or RIGHT JOIN, and applying some suggestions I found on the net, all to no avail.

Note: Answers involving 'CTE' or 'OVER' or 'PARTITION' or 'TOP n' or 'DENSE_RANK' does not work on our office mysql database.